# Flask-Security token login without CSRF - Almost there but not quite

Tags: python, security, authentication, flask, flask-security

I have put in hours in this, and am sure I have a solution that will be useful to many here given the many unanswered questions - if you help me to perfect it

I have a flask Web application that also serves as the backend for my android app.
I wanted to secure my API endpoints with token authentication without globally disabling CSRF Protection.

After all options run out, I decided to modify Flask-security to serve my purpose.
This is my branch. https://github.com/mnjenga/flask-security

In a nutshell, I have created an additional view /api/login that renders a login form whose CSFR is disabled (only that specific form). All other views including /login (in my branch i have amended it to /account/login) retain their CSRF protection. Now when I post to /api/login with the right credentials, I get my token without an error which I can use for any other request. Login API post to /account/login return an error as expected as the view is still protected.

What am now trying to achieve is to make sure the /api/login view is not accessible from a browser or accept any session based authentication (Or is it CSFR safe given it does not return a cookie only a token and I can disable processing of non json posts?)

This is how the /api/login view looks like

```
@anonymous_user_required
def api_login():
    """View function for api_login view"""

    form_class = _security.api_login_form

    if request.is_json:
        form = form_class(MultiDict(request.get_json()))
    else:
        form = form_class(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        login_user(form.user, remember=form.remember.data)
        after_this_request(_commit)

        if not request.is_json:
            return redirect(get_post_login_redirect(form.next.data))

    if request.is_json:
        return _render_json(form, include_auth_token=True)

    return _security.render_template(config_value('LOGIN_USER_TEMPLATE'),
                                     login_user_form=form,
                                     **_ctx('login'))
```

My thoughts currently revolve around making the view process POST method only, replace

```
else:
        form = form_class(request.form)
```

(return an error here)

so that browser forms are not processed, and remove the form rendering.

I go to sleep now with my head almost bursting, I hope I can wake up to some good news

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have finally done it

```
@anonymous_user_required
def api_login():
    """View function for login view"""

    form_class = _security.api_login_form

    if request.is_json:
        form = form_class(MultiDict(request.get_json()))
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            login_user(form.user, remember=form.remember.data)
            after_this_request(_commit)
    else:
        return jsonify(*get_message('INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'))   

    if request.is_json:
        return _render_json(form, include_auth_token=True)

    return jsonify(*get_message('INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'))
```

This ensures only json posts are processed, and everything else in the site is CSRF protected.

I can get my token (here i have used ipython)

```
In [6]: r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/login', data=json
        ...: .dumps({'email':'me@mine.com', 'password':'goodpw'}), header
        ...: s={'content-type': 'application/json'})
    In [7]: r.json()
    Out[7]:
    {'meta': {'code': 200},
     'response': {'user': {'authentication_token':
'WyIyIiwiJDUkcm91bmRzPTUzNTAwMCRMUFBteW9sa0p0b0d3eWFBJGFZakdESE9ZeHBrVEJ1YUN4ZC52QVI4VmtPa0x4bEYzSEhwRGM3b1lqdzYi
    XQ.DTDLqw.DtFvINasBL6SyT2w2xpyOkWnnIk',
       'id': '2'}}}
```

Attempting the same on my normal login view return an error as expected

```
In [8]: r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/account/login', data=
    ...: json.dumps({'email':'me.mine.com', 'password':'goodpw'}), he
    ...: aders={'content-type': 'application/json'})

   In [9]: r.json()
   Out[9]:
   {'meta': {'code': 400},
   'response': {'errors': {'csrf_token': ['The CSRF token is missing.']}}}
```

I am now plan to do the same for registration at some point.
If you wish to test this branch you can install it via pip

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mnjenga/flask-security
```